# ul drop-down menu shifts slightly when page is zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input with an auto suggest drop-down menu. The problem I have is when the page is zoomed, the ul shifts slightly from the input field so it is no longer parallel or flush with the input field. Is there a better way I can do this? I have the code here and also I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSXje/) to demonstrate.

```
.suggestionsBox
{
  position:absolute; 
  top:24px;
  left:37px;
  width:200px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color:fff;
}
.suggestionList
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.suggestionList ul li 
{
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:6px;
}
.suggestionList ul li:hover 
{
 background-color: #DAD6D6;
 color:#000;
}
ul
{
 font-size:12px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 border:1px solid grey;
 border-top:none; 
}
.load
{
  background-position:right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
table
{
  border-collapse:collapse; 
}
#suggest 
{
  position:relative;
}
#email
{
  outline: none; 
  width:200;color:grey;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:2;
} 

<div id = "suggest">
<div>
  <table>
    <td>email:</td>
    <td><input type = "text" id = "email" autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "type something then zoom" /></td>
  </table>

<div class="suggestionsBox" id = "suggestions" style = "display: none;">
<div class="suggestionList" id = "suggestionsList">
</div></div></div></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$('#email').bind('keyup',function() {

            if($('#email').val().length >0) {

                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#suggestionsList').html("<ul><li>now zoom in or out</li><ul>");
          }else $('#suggestions').hide();

     });
```

Comment: couldn't you jst adjust the position http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/sSXje/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so the problem lies with the way each browser handles zooming in bits of text. Mind you, most browsers can handle zooming in and out divs and other fixed size elements quite well, but because text, fonts to be more specific, change character widths quite dramatically, you get inconsistencies like the one you're having.

The problem is solved easily by inserting a container div set to `position: relative` which holds the input and autocomplete div snuggly together. Snuggly? Yeah, snuggly.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2NTV/20/) which should explain everything quite clearly.